# Sitecore the Better Placehoder Layout

Tags: inheritance, key, sitecore, placeholder

Can anybody explain which one (top or bottom) is better??
Briefly, the top has some placeholder elements in the landing page and all key names are like absolute in Sitecore Layout Presentation.

Otherwise, the bottom one has only one placeholder in landing page and it calls "group" control page. The "group" placeholder contains the list of placeholders.

The difference is that I call only one placeholder which is "group" in landing page and the "group" control call its children as inheritance in Sitecore.

If I change the structure to the bottom, do you think the site or page has the better rendering performance?? If yes, why?

[image]

** One more thing, even I didn't set placeholder element for specific control in page, the specific control will be added if the control was created under defined placeholder element. For example, if I add control in "group/a", the new control's key will be "group/a/specific" even it doesn't have its own placeholder element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure last example. You can have different Group Layouts defined for main tags:

- `<header>` -> sc_plh_header
- `<content>` -> sc_plh_content -here you can render your grouped layouts explained below.
- `<footer>`-> sc_plh_header

**sc_plh_content** sitecore placeholder will have grouped placeholders (sublayouts) based on pages type:

content for: Homepage, Sitemap, Article, News, Products, Products Family so on. As that you force your Content Authors to insert controls only in specific placeholders.

Ex:

**Article Family** has left menu navigation and in right tagged similar articles (content [800px] having 3 columns: column 1 [200px] =  leftnav_placeholder, column 2 [ 450]- content_wrapper_placeholder, column 3 [150px] - right_teaser_section)

**News Section** page has only one column with a list of news loaded async at mouse scroll (content centered [600px responsive] - content_infinite_scoll_placeholder).

It's recommend to reduce content editors possibility to create funky pages.

Regards performance both have identical performance (if you have same page one using first example and one second example).

Comment: Is there any advantage of using the bottom picture in Sitecore?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think changing the structure will improve the rendering performance. But it may have other benefits. While I admit that I'm not an expert in the inner workings of how Sitecore assembles a page, it seems likely that there's more code to execute if you have nested sublayouts - which probably implies more time to process them. I wouldn't expect the difference in execution time to be dramatic. But if you're working on a high load website it might still be significant.

That said, I tend to use the nested pattern fairly regularly in my development because it usually fits better with the sort of visual layouts I am asked to create. Web pages often have columns - which might use nested mark-up. Hence I often divide up my implementation components between "Positional Sublayouts" (those which contain placeholders and the mark-up needed to position them on screen - your "Group" is an example of that) and "Behavioural Sublayouts" (those which render content, or perform processing):

[image: Page structure]

Here the positional sublayout includes two placeholders - for the left and right of the page. The child controls can then be placed in the appropriate column.

I find breaking up the page in this way allows for more reusability: The positional sublayouts can be reused across all the pages which share the same column sizes. And the behavioural controls can be reused in pages with different columns.

It's probably worth pointing out that place where you might be able to get performance benefits to the nested approach is through caching - though this can have some challenges: If you enable the Sitecore cache for the "group" control in your nested example, then Sitecore will also cache the output of its child controls in the same cache entry. That could be good for performance if these children do a lot of processing - but it can also cause issues if any of those child controls need to vary between different users or requests. In that scenario you may be better off not caching "group" at all, but setting caching options on the child sublayouts.